# Get Code after Authentication from LinkedIn Redirect Url

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a login page with LinkedIn authentication using Angular and I am getting this URL after logging in to LinkedIn:

```
https://example.com/welcome?code=AQAewReth0-dsds333ffdsAd_HK-CssJdsflds2b1eMsFDWKL3Hu39ssffSgdTxEsum7fT9zs9MMmjY4JUN6dJ8YGnf4tClItIR0noyeW3yX_4_3YKf1yidhxzJxnwnIQ7z59Y3WpCLv4Rdsdsfsf10qUFeO1wwbtQsfsf1FkJsAi9JIxnM8w&state=dse22ds553sf
```

From the above URL, how can I get the string from the `code` URL query parameter?

Comment: The URL provided is not a valid URL

Comment: Try to follow this article https://medium.com/@ellesmuse/how-to-get-a-linkedin-access-token-a53f9b62f0ce

Comment: Yeah I fellow that article. I'm doing it in a different way. I want to know how can I get code from this Url. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can split the URL string on `code=`, then grab the right hand side of the string like this:

```js
const url = 'https://example.com/welcome?code=AQAewReth0-dsds333ffdsAd_HK-CssJdsflds2b1eMsFDWKL3Hu39ssffSgdTxEsum7fT9zs9MMmjY4JUN6dJ8YGnf4tClItIR0noyeW3yX_4_3YKf1yidhxzJxnwnIQ7z59Y3WpCLv4Rdsdsfsf10qUFeO1wwbtQsfsf1FkJsAi9JIxnM8w&state=dse22ds553sf';
const code = url.split('code=')[1]; // This will return AQAewReth0-dsds333ffdsAd_HK-CssJdsflds2b1eMsFDWKL3Hu39ssffSgdTxEsum7fT9zs9MMmjY4JUN6dJ8YGnf4tClItIR0noyeW3yX_4_3YKf1yidhxzJxnwnIQ7z59Y3WpCLv4Rdsdsfsf10qUFeO1wwbtQsfsf1FkJsAi9JIxnM8w&state=dse22ds553sf
```